# Sabre How to create PNR with child and or infant as passenger

Tags: soap, sabre

When I try to create PNR with child and or infant passengers I get this error, however when it is Adult only it works fine. I've read their documentation I don't know what I did wrong. Please help.

Payload :

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="false"  xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
<PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true" >
    <EndTransactionRQ>
        <EndTransaction Ind="true" ></EndTransaction>
        <Source ReceivedFrom="TEST" ></Source>
    </EndTransactionRQ>
</PostProcessing>
<PriceQuoteInfo>
    <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" ></Link>
    <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1" ></Link>
    <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="1" ></Link>
</PriceQuoteInfo>
<SpecialReqDetails>
    <SpecialServiceRQ>
        <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" >
                    <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-03-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1" >
                    <GivenName>JANE</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="2006-03-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1" >
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
        </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    <AgencyInfo>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>address here</AddressLine>
            <CityName>city here</CityName>
            <CountryCode>PH</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>postal code here</PostalCode>
            <StreetNmbr>street number here</StreetNmbr>
        </Address>
        <Ticketing TicketType="7T-" ></Ticketing>
    </AgencyInfo>
    <CustomerInfo>
        <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A" ></ContactNumber>
        </ContactNumbers>
        <Email Address="test.email@someemail.com" ShortText="ABC123" Type="CC" ></Email>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" >
            <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="ADT" >
            <GivenName>JANE</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="3.1" NameReference="C10" PassengerType="CNN" >
            <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
    </CustomerInfo>
</TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

Response :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb='http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader' eb:version='1.0' soap-env:mustUnderstand='1'>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type='URI'>webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type='URI'>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>XXXX</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>PassengerDetailsRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>PassengerDetailsRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>250361059799101760</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2016-07-18T01:39:41</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext'>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType='String' EncodingType='wsse:Base64Binary'>XXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns='http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2'>
            <ApplicationResults xmlns='http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01' status='NotProcessed'>
                <Error type='BusinessLogic' timeStamp='2016-07-17T20:39:41.169-05:00'>
                    <SystemSpecificResults>
                        <Message code='ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE'>CHILD DETAILS REQUIRED IN SSR - ENTER 3CHLD/...</Message>
                    </SystemSpecificResults>
                </Error>
            </ApplicationResults>
        </PassengerDetailsRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Payload with infant :

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="false"  xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2">
<PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true" >
    <EndTransactionRQ>
        <EndTransaction Ind="true" ></EndTransaction>
        <Source ReceivedFrom="TEST" ></Source>
    </EndTransactionRQ>
</PostProcessing>
<PriceQuoteInfo>
    <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" ></Link>
    <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1" ></Link>
    <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="2" ></Link>
    <Link NameNumber="4.1" Record="3" ></Link>
</PriceQuoteInfo>
<SpecialReqDetails>
    <AddRemarkRQ>
        <RemarkInfo>
            <Remark Code="H" SegmentNumber="A" Type="General" >
                <Text>TEXT</Text>
            </Remark>
        </RemarkInfo>
    </AddRemarkRQ>
    <SpecialServiceRQ>
        <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" >
                    <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-03-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1" >
                    <GivenName>JANE</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="2006-03-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1" >
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="2016-01-01" Gender="MI" NameNumber="4.1" >
                    <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="CHLD" >
                <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" ></PersonName>
                <Text>01MAR06</Text>
            </Service>
            <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="INFT" >
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" ></PersonName>
                <Text>DOE/INFANT/01JAN16</Text>
            </Service>
        </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    <AgencyInfo>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine>address here</AddressLine>
            <CityName>city here</CityName>
            <CountryCode>PH</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>postal code here</PostalCode>
            <StreetNmbr>street number here</StreetNmbr>
        </Address>
        <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW" ></Ticketing>
    </AgencyInfo>
    <CustomerInfo>
        <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A" ></ContactNumber>
        </ContactNumbers>
        <Email Address="test.email@someemail.com" ShortText="ABC123" Type="CC" ></Email>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" NameReference="A36" PassengerType="ADT" >
            <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" NameReference="A36" PassengerType="ADT" >
            <GivenName>JANE</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="3.1" NameReference="C10" PassengerType="CNN" >
            <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName Infant="true" NameNumber="4.1" NameReference="I6" PassengerType="INF" >
            <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName>
            <Surname>DOE</Surname>
        </PersonName>
    </CustomerInfo>
</TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

Result with infant :

```
<PassengerDetailsRS xmlns='http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_2'>
        <ApplicationResults xmlns='http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01' status='NotProcessed'>
            <Error type='BusinessLogic' timeStamp='2016-07-20T10:53:30.328-05:00'>
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code='ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE'>CANNOT ASSOC TO INFANT NAME</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Error>
        </ApplicationResults>
</PassengerDetailsRS>
```

EnhancedAirBookRQ : http://pastebin.com/uZtbApR1

Answer (score 5):

I will add some information that will helpful

1) **When child present (CNN)**

add SecureFlight segment

```
<SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
       <PersonName DateOfBirth="2007-05-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1" >
                <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                <Surname>TESTBOOKING</Surname>
       </PersonName> 
</SecureFlight>
```

`Add a SSR for child

```
<Service SSR_Code="CHLD">
      <PersonName NameNumber="2.1"/>
      <Text>01MAY07</Text>
</Service>
```

For SSR we need child DOB as  shown in the exapmle

2) **When INF( infant without seat/lap infant) present**

add SecureFlight segment. 
Make sure in this case as NameNumber use a ADT name number since infant is a lap infant

```
<SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
       <PersonName DateOfBirth="2017-01-20" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" >
                <GivenName>INF</GivenName>
                <Surname>TESTBOOKING</Surname>
       </PersonName> 
</SecureFlight>
```

`Add a SSR for child

```
<Service SSR_Code="INFT">
      <PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
      <Text>TESTBOOKING/INF/20JAN17</Text>
</Service>
```

For SSR we also need ADT NameNumber and for text it should be in this format
**LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME/DATEOFBIRTH** as in exapmle

3) **When INS( infant with seat) present**

add SecureFlight segment. Here we don't need adult NameNumber. but When create Customer Passenger use as `Infant="false"`

```
<SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
       <PersonName DateOfBirth="2017-01-20" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1" >
                <GivenName>INS</GivenName>
                <Surname>TESTBOOKING</Surname>
       </PersonName> 
</SecureFlight>
```

`Add a SSR for child

```
<Service SSR_Code="INFT">
      <PersonName NameNumber="3.1"/>
      <Text>TESTBOOKING/INS/20JAN17/OS</Text>
</Service>
```

For SSR we also need ADT NameNumber and for text it should be in this format
**LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME/DATEOFBIRTH/OS** as in exapmle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change de PQ

```
<Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" ></Link>
<Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="1" ></Link>
<Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="2" ></Link>
```

You put Record="1" in all cases, but you have a child, so your NameNumber 3.1 needs to be associated to Record="2". If you dont do that you will have adt fare for all your passengers.

Edit:

Record="2" is not always for children but also could be for infant, for example if you have 1 ADT + 1 CNN (children) + 1 INF then you need this:

```
<Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" ></Link>
<Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="2" ></Link>
<Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="3" ></Link>
```

Where NameNumber 2.1 and Record 2 are the child passenger, and NameNumber=3 and record 3 are the infant passenger, BUT if you have 1 ADT + 1 INF, then you need:

```
<Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1" ></Link>
<Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="2" ></Link>
```

And now the record 2 and namenumber 2.1 are for infant passenger.

PassengerDetailsRQ:

```
        <soapenv:Body>
        <PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.2.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="true">
            <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true">
                <EndTransactionRQ>
                    <EndTransaction Ind="true"/>
                    <Source ReceivedFrom="TEST"/>
                </EndTransactionRQ>
            </PostProcessing>
            <PriceQuoteInfo>
                <Link NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
                <Link NameNumber="2.1" Record="2"/>
                <Link NameNumber="3.1" Record="3"/>
            </PriceQuoteInfo>
            <SpecialReqDetails>
                <AddRemarkRQ>
                    <RemarkInfo>
                        <Remark Code="H" SegmentNumber="1" Type="General">
                            <Text>TEXT</Text>
                        </Remark>
                    </RemarkInfo>
                </AddRemarkRQ>
                <SpecialServiceRQ>
                    <SpecialServiceInfo>
                        <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" >
                                <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
                                <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                            </PersonName>
                        </SecureFlight>
                        <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                            <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-03-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1" >
                                <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                                <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                            </PersonName>
                        </SecureFlight>
                        <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                            <PersonName DateOfBirth="2006-03-01" Gender="MI" NameNumber="3.1" >
                                <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName>
                                <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                            </PersonName>
                        </SecureFlight>
                        <Service SSR_Code="INFT">
                            <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" />
                            <Text>DOE/INFANT/10OCT15</Text>
                        </Service>
                    </SpecialServiceInfo>
                </SpecialServiceRQ>
            </SpecialReqDetails>
            <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
                <AgencyInfo>
                    <Address>
                        <AddressLine>address here</AddressLine>
                        <CityName>city here</CityName>
                        <CountryCode>PH</CountryCode>
                        <PostalCode>postal code here</PostalCode>
                        <StreetNmbr>street number here</StreetNmbr>
                    </Address>
                    <Ticketing TicketType="7T-" ></Ticketing>
                </AgencyInfo>
                <CustomerInfo>
                    <ContactNumbers>
                        <ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="A" ></ContactNumber>
                        <ContactNumber Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H" ></ContactNumber>
                    </ContactNumbers>
                    <Email Address="test.email@someemail.com" NameNumber="1.1" />
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" >
                        <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
                        <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="CNN" >
                        <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                        <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <PersonName Infant="true" NameNumber="3.1" PassengerType="INF" >
                        <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName>
                        <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </CustomerInfo>
            </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        </PassengerDetailsRQ>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Yep, good point. I focused on trying to overcome the error in the first post, but pricing based on different passenger type might be involved here too.

Comment: Also verify that in your EnhancedAirBook you have <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">  and also for infants the gender are "MI" and "FI".

Comment: Thanks! @JPBlanco , how did u guys know that? There were no description whatsoever in the sabre website. So for Child it will always be Record 2? and for infant it'll be Record 3? Are gender also important to include? Please help me with the infant guys

Comment: @chingchong See my answer i put an example of a PassengerDetailRQ, please if it work mark as correct answer.

Comment: @JPBlanco problem still persist now i get 'CANNOT ASSOC TO INFANT NAME'. I have edited payload and result for with infants above please see them, our payload are just similar.

Comment: @chingchong Please copy your enhancedAirBook request and response, maybe the problem is there

Comment: @JPBlanco i've added it now please see above post

Comment: @chingchong and response please

Comment: @chingchong I saw your EnhancedAirBookRQ,  you have 4 pasengers, my example is for 3 passengers:

Comment: @chingchong Also with NumberInParty="3" you are asking for 3 seats, if you want infant without seat you need to put only the quantity without infants, and also modify your bargainfindermax in SeatsRequested

Comment: @JPBlanco yeah I have 2 ADT 1 CNN and 1 INF the syntax is still the same tho. Sorry I cant send you the response right now I'm already in bed, but the enhanceAirBook response was a success. Btw what is the AddRemark node for?

Comment: @JPBlanco yah i just figured that out a while ago so is it correct? NumberInParty="3" cause I have 4 people and one of them is infant, right?

Comment: http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/SP_Developer_Guide_v3.4.0.pdf ,

Check out this developer guide for Orchestrated Air Booking, page number 21 has the details regarding the record number specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the special service 'CHLD' right after your last SecureFlight element (date of birth format should be DDMMMYY).

```
<SpecialReqDetails>
    <SpecialServiceRQ>
        <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1" >
                    <GivenName>JOHN</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-03-01" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1" >
                    <GivenName>JANE</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" >
                <PersonName DateOfBirth="2006-03-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="3.1" >
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                    <Surname>DOE</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </SecureFlight>
            <Service SSR_Code="CHLD">
                <PersonName NameNumber="3.1"/>
                <Text>20DEC80</Text>
              </Service>
        </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW for infant how would you do it?

Comment: I believe it would be something like this:

<v3:Service SSR_Code="INFT">
       <v3:Text>DOE/BABY/20DEC15</v3:Text>
</v3:Service>

Last and first name need to match what was specified in CustomerInfo/PersonName/GivenName and Surname for the infant.

Comment: Dude now I get "ÂINVALID PSGR TYPEÂ" also I've read somewhere that infant could have a seat. Do you know how to do it with and without seat?

Comment: Did you change your request to include Infant now? If that's the case, then I think that should be a separate question. If we post solutions/answers to different problems in the same post, they will get lost in comments, rather than highlighted in answers on its own post (and that way, it will give more visibility to other community members)

Comment: No, i didn't change the question we are still in the same question read 'Sabre How to create PNR with child and or infant as passenger'. Please help me how to book infant you know how to book child I'm sure you also know how to book infants. I've added my payload and request with infant passenger. Please help @fcarreno

Comment: Not sure if you need <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" ></PersonName> when specifying the infant under SpecialReqDetails/SpecialServiceRQ/SpecialServiceInfo/Service. Try removing that element, or if really needed for INFT Service, I think the infant is your passenger 4.1 not 1.1

Comment: Hi, please check this result = http://pastebin.com/BNFrH0ZV, payload = http://pastebin.com/ADHJpjCm , 2nd testing without the PersonName node = http://pastebin.com/VqdpT1NR

Comment: @fcarreno You need to put NameNumber 1.1 to make the reference to an adult if you dont do that, the booking will fail.