# Infant details required in SSR - Enter 4INFT

Tags: sabre

I'm developing with sabre soap api.
Now, I want to create passenger detail with all passenger types (ADT, CNN, INF)
I have a problem with infant type.
When I post the PassengerDetailRQ -> return 200
But in the EndTransaction response, I received an applicationResults's error message.

I have followed by [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427599/sabre-how-to-create-pnr-with-child-and-or-infant-as-passenger/45966842#45966842) . But not working.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem. Thanks!!!

You can see in the below:

PassengerDetail request:

```
    <PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" version="3.3.0" IgnoreOnError="true" HaltOnError="false">
    <PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true" UnmaskCreditCard="false" />
    <PreProcessing IgnoreBefore="false">
        <UniqueID ID=""/>
    </PreProcessing>
    <PriceQuoteInfo>
        <Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
        <Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="2.1" Record="1"/>
        <Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="3.1" Record="2"/>
        <Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="4.1" Record="3"/>
    </PriceQuoteInfo>
    <SpecialReqDetails>
        <AddRemarkRQ>
            <RemarkInfo>
                <Remark Code="H" SegmentNumber="A" Type="General">
                    <Text>TEST REMARK</Text>
                </Remark>
            </RemarkInfo>
        </AddRemarkRQ>
        <SpecialServiceRQ>
            <SpecialServiceInfo>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                        <GivenName>FATHER MR</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="1989-06-25" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1">
                        <GivenName>MOTHER MRS</GivenName>
                        <Surname>LINUX</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2010-03-23" Gender="F" NameNumber="3.1">
                        <GivenName>CHILD MS</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName DateOfBirth="2018-01-23" Gender="MI" NameNumber="4.1">
                        <GivenName>INFANT MSTR</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </SecureFlight>
                <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="CHLD">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" />
                    <Text>23MAR10</Text>
                </Service>
                <Service SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="INFT">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" />
                    <Text>SUR/INFANT MSTR/23SEP17</Text>
                </Service>
            </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </SpecialServiceRQ>
    </SpecialReqDetails>        
    <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
        <AgencyInfo>
            <Ticketing TicketType="7T-"/>
        </AgencyInfo>
        <CustomerInfo>
            <ContactNumbers>
                <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" LocationCode="HAN" Phone="091-666-3333" PhoneUseType="B"/>
            </ContactNumbers>
            <Email Address="LYVIETANH@GMAIL.COM" NameNumber="1.1" ShortText="ABC123" Type="CC"/>
            <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                <GivenName>FATHER MR</GivenName>
                <Surname>SUR</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                <GivenName>MOTHER MRS</GivenName>
                <Surname>LINUX</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="3.1" PassengerType="CNN" NameReference="C02">
                <GivenName>CHILD MS</GivenName>
                <Surname>SUR</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName Infant="true" NameNumber="4.1" PassengerType="INF" NameReference="I13">
                <GivenName>INFANT MSTR</GivenName>
                <Surname>SUR</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
    </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

PassengerDetail response:

```
        <PassengerDetailsRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
            <Success timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:26.163-05:00"/>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:25.226-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.INVALID ACTION</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
            <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:25.451-05:00">
                <SystemSpecificResults>
                    <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">CHECK ITINERARY</Message>
                </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Warning>
        </ApplicationResults>
        <TravelItineraryReadRS>
            <TravelItinerary>
                <CustomerInfo>
                    <ContactNumbers>
                        <ContactNumber LocationCode="HAN" Phone="091-666-3333-B-1.1" RPH="001"/>
                    </ContactNumbers>
                    <PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="01.01" RPH="1">
                        <Email Comment="CC/ABC123">LYVIETANH@GMAIL.COM</Email>
                        <GivenName>FATHER MR</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="02.01" RPH="2">
                        <GivenName>MOTHER MRS</GivenName>
                        <Surname>LINUX</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <PersonName WithInfant="false" NameNumber="03.01" NameReference="C02" RPH="3">
                        <GivenName>CHILD MS</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                    <PersonName WithInfant="true" NameNumber="04.01" NameReference="I13" RPH="4">
                        <GivenName>INFANT MSTR</GivenName>
                        <Surname>SUR</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </CustomerInfo>
                <ItineraryInfo>
                    ... I REMOVED THIS DATA ...
                </ItineraryInfo>
                <RemarkInfo>
                    <Remark RPH="001" Type="General">
                        <Text>TEST REMARK</Text>
                    </Remark>
                </RemarkInfo>
                <SpecialServiceInfo RPH="001" Type="AFX">
                    <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
                        <PersonName NameNumber="04.01">I/SUR/INFANT MSTR</PersonName>
                        <Text>VN INF</Text>
                    </Service>
                </SpecialServiceInfo>
            </TravelItinerary>
        </TravelItineraryReadRS>
```

EndTransaction request:

```
<EndTransactionRQ Version="2.0.8" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
    <Source ReceivedFrom="SWS TEST" />
</EndTransactionRQ>
```

EndTransaction response:

```
        <EndTransactionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.8">
        <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:31-05:00">
                <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    <stl:Message>INFANT DETAILS REQUIRED IN SSR - ENTER 4INFT/...</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
        </stl:ApplicationResults>
    </EndTransactionRS>
```

Comment: Resolved. I used sabre command to instead of

Answer (score 1):

If you check in the response `PassengerDetailsRS/TravelItineraryReadRS/TravelItinerary/SpecialServiceInfo` you'll see that none of the special services were added, and for that reason it is requested at the time of the *EndTransaction* call.

Without knowing the status of the itinerary, it is impossible to state the cause of the 2 warnings returned:

```
<ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="Complete">
    <Success timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:26.163-05:00"/>
    <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:25.226-05:00">
        <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.INVALID ACTION</Message>
        </SystemSpecificResults>
    </Warning>
    <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-06-15T12:11:25.451-05:00">
        <SystemSpecificResults>
            <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">CHECK ITINERARY</Message>
        </SystemSpecificResults>
    </Warning>
</ApplicationResults>
```

I would guess UC segments in the itinerary.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggest.

Comment: I've tried again. But flight segment is already "SS" on status when EnhancedAirBook is used. I dont know why it always appear these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Between the "CHECK ITINERARY" error and the "ENTER 4INFT/..." message on save, it would appear you are working with an AA itinerary, and are sending a 3INFT command.
When airline is AA, you need to switch almost all commands starting with a 3 to starting with a 4. ie instead of sending 3INFT/... you send 4INFT/...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you explain more detail for me? ie. request body. Thanks.